# Upgrade MongoDB using "mongod --upgrade"

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to upgrade my MongoDB Replica set from 4.2 to 4.4.

I some places I see an instruction to use the "mongod --upgrade" command after replacing the binaries to the new versions, but in other places it does not specify this command as a requirement.

Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Tamar

Comment: Follow this instruction: [Upgrade a Replica Set to 4.4](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/release-notes/4.4-upgrade-replica-set/)

Answer (score -1):

If the mongod service is running, launch the command on mongodb console to enable the features of that version.
In this case: `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.4" } );`